# Intent an activity

Tags: listview, android-intent

I am trying to call an activity from lisview but when i call intent my app crash i am trying with a bla activity but crash too, my listview is inside a tabwidget can somebody helpme plese.

this is my code.

```
                        lstResumen.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                try {

                                    //Obtiene el cursor asignado a este listview
                                    Cursor Cursor_Resumen = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                    //Llena las variables con los valores correspondientes
                                    Global.Parametro1 = Cursor_Resumen.getString(Cursor_Resumen.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                                    Global.Parametro2 = Cursor_Resumen.getString(Cursor_Resumen.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id_precio"));
                                    //I02.9622.157
                                    Cursor_Resumen.close();

                                    int Cantidad_Fichas = 0;
                                    String SWhere = "";
                                    SWhere = "id_producto=?";

                                    //Verifica si ya se ingreso ficha para este producto si no se ha ingresado llama el activity de fichas
                                    margs = new String[]{Global.Parametro1};
                                    Cantidad_Fichas = manager.Consulta_Campo_Int("ifnull(count(*),0) AS cuantos", "cuantos", SWhere, "fichas", margs);

                                    if (Cantidad_Fichas == 0) {

                                        try {

                                            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Serie.class);
                                            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);


                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            message = e.getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Esta ficha ya fue ingresada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        return;
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    message = e.getMessage();
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }

                        });
```

---

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.creceactivaciones.itecandroidice.app, PID: 11065
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.creceactivaciones.itecandroidice.app/com.creceactivaciones.itecandroidice.app.Serie}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 5 is null
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2964)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2993)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 5 is null
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1278)
                      at com.creceactivaciones.itecandroidice.app.dbManager.Series_Promotores(dbManager.java:1231)
                      at com.creceactivaciones.itecandroidice.app.Serie.onResume(Serie.java:127)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1197)
                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5343)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2950)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2993) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your `Series` activity, that it cannot start for some reasons, not this piece of code.